# Self managed monotonically increasing key OR systems's timestamp

Tags: java, database, oracle

We have an use-case where we keep a monotonically increasing key signifying the current version of a customer data. It is used in the system to figure out the most recent version and resolve the conflict for third party callers if there is delay between reading the data and its processing and they get multiple versions.

```
CUSTOMER_RESOURCE_ID   CURRENT_VERSION
132323                  1234
```

If something changes for this resource, we increment the version from 1234 to 1235 (it is totally fine even if we increase it to 1300 as long as it doesn't go down). For this, we need to first read the value and then update it.

Other alternative is to use DB's timestamp and keep updating version with the DB timestamp which will always be increasing. Since this is just one system, clock-skew can only happen when we change the DB. Also, we are not super concerned about the the case when multiple threads update the data within a fraction of time (i.e. least granularity of the timestamp) as we have another lock as per which only one thread updates the resource at one time.

I was wondering if we could use database's system timestamp to avoid the select-and-increment with just-update.

Is there any concern with this approach? I assume that it will be less overhead on the database but I don't know how much we save here.

Comment: Can you explain with an example?

Comment: Depending on the granularity of the system clock you probably won't be able to guarantee uniqueness among multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks, please see the update.

Comment: What is the version number used for?

Comment: If there's locking involved, I doubt there's much of an advantage over select+update.

Answer (score 0):

Many approaches can be discussed. In my opinion;

-- You can use incremental squence that even default column value instead of database timestamp.  Maybe miliseconds can make problem for you.

--In addition, If your table is not very big and your resources is enough, you can add a is_last_version column which will update with every insert to query last version of customers in a perfomance(ie. `select * from customers where customer_id = 123 and is_last_version= 1`--to get rid of the cost of ordering). So, you can know which row is the last version. But each insert time will be longer. You should test it.

Example:

CUSTOMER_RESOURCE:

```
CUSTOMER_RESOURCE_ID   CURRENT_VERSION_ID         IS_LAST_VERSION          INSERT_TIME
                        (default seq)                                (default sysdate --optionally)
132323                      1                            1               
132324                      2                            1
132325                      3                            1                      
132326                      4                            0
132327                      5                            0
132328                      6                            1
132326                      7                            0 
132329                      8                            1
132326                      9                            1
132327                      10                           1
```

When insert:

```
update CUSTOMER_RESOURCE 
SET IS_LAST_VERSION = 0
where CUSTOMER_RESOURCE_ID = 132326;

insert into CUSTOMER_RESOURCE(CUSTOMER_RESOURCE_ID,IS_LAST_VERSION) VALUES (132326,1);
COMMIT;
```

When select Last Version of a customer:

```
select * from customers where customer_id = 123 and is_last_version= 1;
```